# How to Strip A Symbol in Relocation

Tags: c, gcc, linker, binutils

i try to remove a symbol from object file as below:

```
gcc -c test.c 

strip --strip-symbol=test_sym test.o test.o
```

`test_sym` is a function implemented in `test.c`.

`strip` returns following message :

```
strip: not stripping symbol 'test_sym' because it is named in a relocation.
```

That error arise since the symbol is implemented in the same file. However is there a way to remove that symbol ?

Comment: If you don't need the symbol to be externally visible, you can declare the function as `static`.

Comment: my aim is to do that task without any change on source code

Comment: OK, so see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678896/limiting-the-scope-of-global-symbols-from-linked-objects).

Comment: my friend i tried that link before. But my problem : try to make undefine implemented symbol in object file. Becuase defined symbol cannot be stripped by strip. Linker definitions work for undefined symbol linking process and  restrict libraries symbols usage by localalize or hidden them, then link process skip those library symbols.

Comment: This is mostly happening because it is being used in the same object file. It would be better if you can put your test.c code as well.